# Can't find way to access state of a specific checkbutton in a dictionary of checkbuttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have searched everywhere (except where the answer might be) and coupled with my in-experience that I can't for the life of me show how to set 'on' (or 'off') a specific (single) checkbutton in a dictionary of checkbuttons. The 'cut-down' code from a larger program shown below, creates 4 checkbuttons and how I read and set ALL 4 checkbuttons.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, IntVar, Button, Checkbutton

light_list = ["Front  ", "Drive  ", "Back   ", "Side   "]
light_dict = {}

def doButtons():
    r=2
    c=0
    for  i, light_item in  enumerate(light_list):
        
        # Set the text for each checkbutton
        light_dict[light_item] = Checkbutton(lights_frame, text=light_item)

        # Create a new instance of IntVar() for each checkbutton
        light_dict[light_item].var = IntVar()

        # Set the variable parameter of the checkbutton
        light_dict[light_item]['variable'] = light_dict[light_item].var

        # Arrange the checkbutton in the window
        light_dict[light_item].grid(row=r, column=c)
        r=r+1

    # create a button to allow checking (activate) the checkbutton status    
    next_button = Button(lights_frame, text="Activate", command=lambda: setDict('', light_dict),
                            justify='right',  relief='raised', bd=6)
    next_button.grid(row=7, column=1) #, pady=50

    # show the contents of the dictionary containing the checkboxes after creation
    print(light_dict)

    # show the values of each checkbox
    printDict('1. Checkbutton values before set:\t', light_dict)

    # Add code here to be able to 'set-on' or 'set-off' a sslected checkbutton
    #(eg 'Drive' in this example)
    # ???????
   
# set each checkbutton in the dictionary to 'on' (1)
def setDict(str, dict):
    print(str,'',end='')
    for  a in dict.values():
        a.var.set(1)

    printDict('2. Checkbuttons values after set:\t', light_dict)

# print the values of each checkbutton in the dictionary
def printDict(str, dict):
    print(str,' :-\t ',end='')
    for  cb in dict.values():
        print(cb.var.get(),' ', end='')
    print('\n')

root=Tk()
lights_frame = Frame(root, width=650, height=420) 
lights_frame.grid()

doButtons()

root.mainloop()
```

Can someone please show me the code how to reference just one of the checkbuttons so I can set or reset the value.

Comment: You already have it: `light_dict['Front  ']` for example. It is better to strip all the trailing spaces in the strings of `light_list`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks a million. The extra spaces were in fact my downfall - I had tried light_dict['Drive'].var.set(1) and got an error I didn't understand. Life's a learning experience!

Answer (score -1):

> Can someone please show me the code how to reference just one of the
> checkbuttons so I can set or reset the value

In line 15, Change this:

```
light_dict[light_item].var = IntVar()
```

to:

```
light_dict[light_item].var = IntVar(value=i)
```